# Can gdal_calc output VRTs?

Tags: gdal, vrt

I'm working with 0.5m resolutions DSM'S and DTM's. and need to calculate a canopy height model. My question is: Is ".vrt" a possible output format for a gdal_calc operation?

Comment: Why on earth ask something that you can test yourself faster? Use  `--format=VRT` and tell us what happened.

Comment: ERROR 1: Writing through VRTSourcedRasterBand is not supported.

Comment: maybe its because i used already vrt-files as input. but they are to huge to convert them in tif:/

Comment: Now your question makes more sense. Make one more trial with any small tiff file as input.

Comment: same error. maybe I need another method for calculating my CHM

Comment: how large are the files? perhaps you can use another file format (i.e KEA)?

Comment: https://gis.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 4):

No, you can't use VRT as an output format for `gdal_calc.py`.

[`gdal_calc.py`](http://www.gdal.org/gdal_calc.html) reads raster data into numpy arrays, performs the requested calculation and writes the resulting numpy array out to a raster file on disk.

You can create a VRT with the calculation required to derive it using python code embedded in the VRT. See [the docs](https://gdal.org/drivers/raster/vrt.html#using-derived-bands-with-pixel-functions-in-python) for more information about the VRT derived band pixel functions written in Python.